# How to hide the spin in QDateEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried hide the spin in my QDateEdit but I cant, how can I hide him? I'm Reading the documentation but cant find how to.
thx2all.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [setButtonSymbols](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractspinbox.html#setButtonSymbols) method which is inherited from [QAbstractSpinBox](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractspinbox.html). There is an option [NoButtons](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractspinbox.html#ButtonSymbols-enum) which suppresses displaying the buttons:

```
date_edit.setButtonSymbols(QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
```

Comment: This work perfect, thank you so much. I'm triying this for days.